# How to add record into the database using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to add a record into a database but its showing me a error: `An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code` i get this error when i run my program, it does not even open my view in web-browser

This is my model:

```
public class MovieModel
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string FirstName { set; get; }
    public string SecondName { set; get; }
    public DateTime DOB { set; get; }
    public string Type{ set; get; }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
namespace Movie.Controllers
{
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        //
        // GET: /Movies/
        public ActionResult AddUsers(MovieModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Movies.Add(model);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

**Second Question** when up-grading my database `upgrade-database` how do i specify a forgone key? is this have to be done via microsoft sql server management?

Comment: you probably tried to insert null data into non-nullable field or duplicate data in a unique field. Make sure that DoB column is not DateTime.Max or DateTime.Min when you do SaveChanges

Comment: Can you tell me the inner exception?

Comment: @ManishMishra i get the error when i run this program, it does not evens display my form.

Comment: @Rohan i've included in my question

Comment: This is the stack trace i am asking for the inner exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This occurs when you are trying to add/insert a record in an object other than a `table`. Is `Movie` a table or a view?

If it is a table, be sure your table has a `primary key` which doesn't allow duplication.

If not add the primary key and **update the Entity Framework model** and run again.

UPDATES : You can create an empty get action. To do so, update your controller as follows

```
    //
    // GET: /Movies/
    public ActionResult AddStudent()
    {
        return View();
    }


     //
    // POST: /Movies/
    [Post]
    public ActionResult AddStudent(MovieModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Movies.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: when i run my view i get the error, my form does not even open. Movie is a table

Comment: this is my primary key `public int ID { set; get; }` And movie is my project - (my mistake)

Comment: Read my answer again, I added some important updates.