# Angular - 400 Error (Bad Request) when using PUT

Tags: c#, angular

In my Angular program, I'm trying to post a row that's entered by the user from my table to my database. But, whenever I use put, in the console, I'm getting an error that's saying

`PUT 400 (Bad Request)`

and the response that I'm getting from the server is

`{"Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult PutPTOData(Int32, PTOTracker.Models.PTOData)' in 'PTOTracker.Controllers.PTODataController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."}`

It's saying that I'm not entering an ID but I thought I was.

Here's my model:

```
namespace PTOTracker.Models
{
public class PTOData
{
[Key]
public int ID { get; set; }
public int EmpKey { get; set; }
public string type { get; set; }
public DateTime date { get; set; }
public string fullhalf { get; set; }
public int hours { get; set; }
public string scheduled { get; set; }
public string notes { get; set; }
public bool inPR { get; set; }
public DateTime? prDate { get; set; }
```

}
  }

here's my save function from my component:

```
    saveNewRow(): void {
    this.ptoDataService.save(this.newRow)
        .then(PTOData => {
            this.ptoData.push({
                ID: 123456,
                EmpKey: this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].EmpKey,
                type: this.selectedType,
                date: this.newRow.date,
                fullhalf: this.newRow.fullhalf,
                hours: this.newRow.hours,
                scheduled: this.newRow.scheduled,
                notes: this.newRow.notes,
                inPR: (this.newRow.inPR ? true : false),
                prDate: this.newRow.prDate
            })
        })

   }
```

and here's my save function in my service:

```
    save(pto: PTOData): Promise<PTOData> {
    return this.http
        .put(this.ptoDateUrl + '/' + pto.ID, pto, this.options)
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => res.json().data as PTOData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Here's my PTODataController:

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using PTOTracker.Models;

namespace PTOTracker.Controllers
{
    public class PTODataController : ApiController
    {
        private PTOTrackerContext db = new PTOTrackerContext();

        // GET: api/PTOData
        public IQueryable<PTOData> GetPTODatas()
        {
            return db.PTODatas;
        }

        // GET: api/PTOData/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(PTOData))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetPTOData(int id)
        {
            PTOData pTOData = db.PTODatas.Find(id);
            if (pTOData == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(pTOData);
        }

      // PUT: api/PTOData/5
      [HttpPut]
      [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
      [Route("api/PTOData/{id}")]
        public IHttpActionResult PutPTOData(int id, PTOData pTOData)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != pTOData.ID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(pTOData).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!PTODataExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        // POST: api/PTOData
        [ResponseType(typeof(PTOData))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostPTOData(PTOData pTOData)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.PTODatas.Add(pTOData);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = pTOData.ID }, pTOData);
        }

        // DELETE: api/PTOData/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(PTOData))]
        public IHttpActionResult DeletePTOData(int id)
        {
            PTOData pTOData = db.PTODatas.Find(id);
            if (pTOData == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.PTODatas.Remove(pTOData);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(pTOData);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool PTODataExists(int id)
        {
            return db.PTODatas.Count(e => e.ID == id) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add the Web API code. Your angular code and the Model definition are irrelevant for this problem

Comment: Looks like `this.newRow` does not have an ID. If your database has an auto incremental key it looks like you're performing the wrong insert into your database.

Comment: We need to see your backend service function

Comment: @mjwills updated OP

Comment: If you `console.log(this.ptoDateUrl + '/' + pto.ID); ` prior to the `this.http` call, what is written to the console?

Comment: @mjwills `api/PTOData/undefined` so that should mean that I don't have an ID even though I'm pretty sure I do, right?

Comment: @mjwills but isn't me pushing`ID: 123456` in my `saveNewRow` function basically guaranteeing that there should be an ID?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147367/discussion-between-rcarc-and-mjwills).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to add the record to the database is not correct.

Firstly, change the JS side of things as per camaron's solution.

Then on the server side, you need to add your entity to the database. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22222636/34092 has a great sample.

```
db.Entry(pTOData).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

needs to be changed to:

```
db.PTODatas.Add(pTOData);
```

and:

```
return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
```

needs to be changed to:

```
return Ok(pTOData);
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be this:

```
saveNewRow(): void {
this.ptoDataService.save(this.newRow)
    .then(PTOData => {
        this.ptoData.push({
            ID: 123456,
            EmpKey: this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].EmpKey,
            type: this.selectedType,
            date: this.newRow.date,
            fullhalf: this.newRow.fullhalf,
            hours: this.newRow.hours,
            scheduled: this.newRow.scheduled,
            notes: this.newRow.notes,
            inPR: (this.newRow.inPR ? true : false),
            prDate: this.newRow.prDate
        })
    })
```

}

You are pushing your new object after you made the request, not before.
Should be something like this:

```
this.ptoDataService.save({
                ID: 123456,
                EmpKey: this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].EmpKey,
                type: this.selectedType,
                date: this.newRow.date,
                fullhalf: this.newRow.fullhalf,
                hours: this.newRow.hours,
                scheduled: this.newRow.scheduled,
                notes: this.newRow.notes,
                inPR: (this.newRow.inPR ? true : false),
                prDate: this.newRow.prDate})
    .then((response: any) => { //do what you want with the response.})
```